# open a terminal at the same window the GUI is at?

Tags: 14.04

Is there a way to do this. I often find myself browsing files in the GUI because it is convenient and then I need a terminal so I have to open one up and cd /dsf/sd/f/sd/f/sd/fsdf with autocomplete it is quicker than typing, but it would be nice to have a shortcut to just open a terminal with one click

Comment: I know that the `Thunar` file explorer that comes installed in the XFCE4 Desktop has the right-click Open Terminal Here command.  `sudo apt-get install thunar`

Answer (score 2):

In the default Ubuntu file browser, Nautilus, this is quite easy to do. (Nautilus is included with Ubuntu, Ubuntu GNOME and possibly Ubuntu MATE.)

Navigate to the desired folder, hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd>, right click and select the `Open Terminal Here` option.

If you happen to use KDE, I believe that the same procedure will work. If you have XFCE, then you're set. As [Terrance](https://askubuntu.com/users/231142/terrance) said, Thunar has the option on a simple right click.

If holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> doesn't work, try this:
Open a terminal and run `sudo apt-get install nautilus-open-terminal`. Once that finishes, relog, and there should be an "open in terminal" option in the right click menu.

Comment: tihs does not work for me in standard 14.04 with nautilus. I get the standard right click, new folder..new document menu

Comment: Pressing Shift?

Comment: yes, I am pressing shift

Comment: Weird. Well, there is another way, which I'm editing in now.

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: still not working :(

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu Unity or something else?

Comment: I am using unity

Comment: @markkirby I've anyways had to press shift for it to work

Comment: @markkirby Hmm. I have 15.10. Are you sure you didn't install anything that included some plugin? There are alternatives to what's in my answer.

Comment: Not that I am aware of, this is a prittey new install, +1 anyway then, if you have to press shift

Comment: @deltaskelta that is strange. I've never had that issue.